# JSON Parsing Returns Null For Large Values Only

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'll keep this brief. I'm using this code to parse JSON from a local file into an array of objects:

```
-(void)populateData
{
    NSString* sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"ships" ofType:@"json"];

    //get json string
    NSString* JSONData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:sourcePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    NSData* data = [JSONData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //put json in array
    ships = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", ships);
}
```

(Note: only showed one for the sake of brevity, there's ~20 entries in each one)

This method works for JSON formatted like this:

```
[
  {
  "name": "Santa Maria",
  "operator": "Kingdom of Spain",
  "flag": "flag_spain"
  }
  ]
```

It returns null for JSON formatted like this:

```
[
  {
  "name": "Santa Maria",
  "operator": "Kingdom of Spain",
  "flag": "flag_spain",
  "launched": "November 19, 1890",
  "fate": "Destroyed in Havana, Cuba in Feburary 1898."
  "cost":"$4,677,788.75",
  "image": "maine_img",
  "image_attribution": "Image is in the public domain."
  }]
```

I haven't the faintest idea of why the smaller one works while the larger one doesn't. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the error message tell you?

Comment: There was none because I had the error callback for the JSON parsing set to nil.

Comment: Because I would just pass over the errors anyways; so long as they don't crash it, don't care about the JSON errors.

Comment: But sometimes those error messages tell you something.

Comment: So instead of letting the parser tell you what the problem is, you ask us here? Did I get that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a comma missing after:

```
  "fate": "Destroyed in Havana, Cuba in Feburary 1898."
```

Comment: That's what I get for copy-pasting after doing one of the items... Thanks for the eye-spotting-stuff. (Gotta wait for 10 minutes to accept the answer)

Answer (score 2):

It's due to a syntax error on this line:

```
"fate": "Destroyed in Havana, Cuba in Feburary 1898."
```

(missing comma at the end)

There are tools to spot this kind of errors. For instance, http://jsonlint.com. This one seems to have better error messages http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

Answer (score 0):

And excuse me, but converting from NSData to NSString and then back to NSData is just pointless. Just call dataWithContensOfFile: and be done with it.